# How do I know when using the Euler Lagrange equations that I have found a minimum of the action

Tags: physics, classical-mechanics, euler-lagrange-equation, hamilton-equations

When looking at a physical system where I have the lagrangian. How do I know I have found a minimum using the EL equations (since according to the principle of least action we need a minimum) as opposed to a maximum.

Comment: Without extra information you don't.

Comment: The "least" in "principle of least action" is a very misleading term, because all you're looking for is curves for which the variation of the action is $0$. So more properly, it should be called "Principle of Stationary Action". I guess people call it "principle of least action" simply out of habit/historical reasons/ it sounds nicer/ quicker to say...